# Firebase Admin SDK in NodeJS - Usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

Am trying to use the Firebase Admin SDK in my NodeJS project, for creating an API. But am a bit confused on the usage.

I have installed the package like this:

```
npm install firebase-admin
```

And in the entry point file (`index.js`), I have added the following lines (used actual values instead of the placeholders):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


//---------- FIREBASE -------------------
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://myprojectname.firebaseio.com"
});
//---------- /FIREBASE -------------------

//.. my other code goes here.. like middlewares, routes, etc.
```

Am gonna use the `firebase-admin` to validate the token in my auth controller (separate file). So do I have to move this code for firebase section from the above `index.js` to my auth controller file?

I mean I have to require and init the firebase-admin in each file from which I want to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main options are:

1. Import and initialize the SDK in each file where you need it.
2. Have a single file that initialize the SDK. Import that file and the SDK into each file where you need it, but don't initialize it everywhere anymore.
3. Have a single file that initializes and exports the SDK. Then import that file everywhere, and use the Firebase services from its export.

I see the third option most commonly, but also regularly see developers struggling with the exports. So you might want to give the second option a try first.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will go with #2 now